# Applescript going over to next process before completing previuos process

Tags: applescript

Allright I am putting it straight -

While testing the script I've noticed that the script can get ahead of the app.
For example, the app may be opening a document which may take a few seconds however applescript has moved on. I've been able to spot this more easily by placing some 'display dialogs' in certain places.

```
tell application "Keynote"
    activate
    open keynoteFile -- STEP 1
    activate
    tell front document -- STEP 2
        delete (every slide where slide number is not equal to (incrementSlideIndex as string))
        save
    end tell
end tell
```

In the above snippet before completion of step 1,script is going over to step 2.

i.e. Despite the keynoteFile hasn't opened completely,the script is moving over to step 2.

**So,how can I make my script complete a process/action before stepping into next action.**

Comment: Your script is a mess. Can you 1. edit your text to better explain what you're trying to accomplish, & 2. comment each section of your script to explain what you're trying to accomplish with that section.

Comment: I hope now it would be clear.